# How to make one File of different images?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have question which i wanna discuss with u. i am a fresh gradutate and just got a job as IT programmer. my company is making a game, the images or graphics use inside the game have one folder but different files of images. They give me task that how we can convert different files of images into one file and  the program still  access that file. If u have any kind of idea share with me ..Thanks

Comment: What approaches have you come up with? What are the different pros and cons of each? What have you coded up yet? Please understand that Stack Overflow will not do your work for you - it is here to help with _specific_ programming questions.

Comment: Hmm... what about compressing the data directory into a zip file?

Comment: But if I can compressing in zip bt still when u click it i again same different files open. I wanna one .exe file of different images?How i can pack different files of images in one and program still access that file ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the *advantage* of this approach is for a game that runs on the desktop, but if you've already carefully considered that and decided that having a single file is important, then it's certainly possible to do so.

Since the question, as Oded [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728699/how-to-make-one-file-of-different-images#comment22345181_15728699), shows very little research or otherwise effort on your part, I won't provide a complete solution. And even if I wanted to do so, I'm not sure I could because you don't give us any information on what programming language and UI framework you're using. Visual Studio 2010 supports a lot of different ones.

Anyway, the trick involves creating a sprite. This is a fairly common technique for web design, where it actually is helpful to reduce load times by using only a single image, and you can find plenty of explanation and examples by searching the web. For example, [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Basically, what you do is make one large image that contains all of your smaller images, offset from each other by a certain number of pixels. Then, you load that single large image and access the individual images by specifying the offset coordinates of each image.

I do not, however, recommend doing as Jan [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728699/how-to-make-one-file-of-different-images/15729350#comment22345271_15728699) and compressing the image directory (into a ZIP file or any other format), because then you'll just have to pay the cost of uncompressing it *each time* you want to use one of the images. That also buys you extremely little; disk storage is cheap nowadays.

Comment: I have almost done my work . Now i wanna to give that project to client bt I am little confuse about graphic folder beacuse i gave the reference of the folder in mu program coding. If i give that folder to client ,it is looking awkward. I wanna alternative solution rather than give this folder of images.